# Musical typing stops working - Logic Pro X

Tags: logic

Sometimes (usually after having been working in Logic for an extended period of time) the musical typing keyboard stops working and instead of playing sounds, the keys trigger the functions that they do when the musical typing keyboard is not open (the sounds play if I press the on-screen keyboard with the mouse, the problem occurs when pressing the keys on my physical keyboard). If I restart Logic the problem goes away.

Anyone encountered this problem and know how to fix it without restarting Logic? I'm using Logic Pro X on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.

I do have a software instrument track selected etc.

Comment: Help us to help you - what version of Logic & OS X ?

Answer (score 1):

same issue - Logic Pro 10.3.1 on Mac OS 10.12.5

musical typing keyboard works as expected, and then becomes unresponsive after some period of time

restarting fixes the glitch and we would need to report this bug to Apple and/or update Logic to hope it gets fixed as a bug.